# Looking for a simple X Window panel/dock with icon "pinning" feature from Windows 7

Tags: xorg, software-rec, openbox

I am using OpenBox WM and I am looking for some simple dock application (that could be used along with OpenBox) that has this icon "pinning" feature. It can also be a panel. So far I have found this:

- Docky - it's fine but it needs compositing manager
- wbar - compiles but isn't working for me (does not appear), and I am not sure if it has the "pin" feature

Any other tools that can do this?

Comment: Docks that need compositing can be run on OpenBox WM with `xcompmgr`

Comment: Yeah I know but this combination turned out its problematic on upgraded Fedora 14.

Comment: Please note wbar does NOT have the pinning feature. It also have problems with multiple monitors.

Comment: @lzap: You should describe what “icon pinning” means (your question is now the first Google hit!).

Comment: Okay. Sorry.Icon on the panel

Comment: Okay - I have an icon on the panel so I can start an application with it. Now - when I start the app the icon "changes" from a starter to a task automatically.

Comment: Or in other way - icon on the taskbar (I prefer icons) can be "pinned" so when I quit an application the icon remains there and I can restart the app with it.

Comment: Is this really required? What's wrong with having the oldstyle quicklaunch bar? What benefit does having a dedicated icon for both? Except that if the program is already running, it's really unintuitive to open a new window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docks that do not require compositing:

- [tint2](http://code.google.com/p/tint2/)
- [simdock](http://simdock.sourceforge.net/)
- [tablaunch](http://tablaunch.sourceforge.net/)
- [bbdock](http://bbdock.nethence.com/)

Comment: The tint2 looks good. The only question is pinning here.

Comment: Tint2 is my answer. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 2):

adeskbar; dock on a diet
bmpanel; tint2 like panel but with 'pinning' possible

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Avant Window Navigator / AWN](https://launchpad.net/awn)? It has the pinning feature you're after and does not require compositing although doesn't work well without it (for example you can't customise the theme). So far it's the best panel I've come across, mainly because of the pinning feature :)

Answer (score 1):

- [Cairo dock](http://www.glx-dock.org/)
- [ADeskBar](https://launchpad.net/adeskbar)